# Java dates problem

Tags: java, datetime, date

I'd like to ask a question. I have a list which contains Dates, for example:

Fri Jan 07 00:00:00 CET 2011
Fri Jan 07 00:01:00 CET 2011
Fri Jan 07 00:03:00 CET 2011
Fri Jan 07 00:05:00 CET 2011
Fri Jan 07 00:06:00 CET 2011

And then the user input an interval minute, like: 2
I have to get every date from list which are between 2 minutes.
The output schould look like this:

```
 
1.                    
Fri Jan 07 00:00:00 CET 2011    
Fri Jan 07 00:01:00 CET 2011 

2.   
Fri Jan 07 00:03:00 CET 2011  
Fri Jan 07 00:05:00 CET 2011   

3.
Fri Jan 07 00:06:00 CET 2011
```

The problem is, I don't know how to do that. Any idea are welcome. :)

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "2 minute interval".  Do you mean [00:00,02:00), [02:00,04:00), [04:00,06:00), etc. (i.e. fixed intervals not including the right endpoint) or events occurring within 2 minutes of an event.  What would the output be for the input events 00:00, 01:00, 02:00, 02:30, 02:45, 05:00, 05:10, 06:10, 07:10 ?

Comment: I mean [00:00,02:00), [02:00,04:00), [04:00,06:00)], for example.

input: 00:00, 01:00, 02:00, 02:30, 02:45, 05:00, 05:10, 06:10, 07:10
interval: 2 minute

output:

1.
00:00, 01:00, 02:00
2.
02:30, 02:45
3.
05:00, 05:10, 06:10
4.
07:10

Comment: "I'd like to ask a question."  Yes, what is it?  Note that "The problem is, I don't know how to do that." in not a question.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** based on your comments:
Sort by date.  Start with the lowest date, add any dates to it within the interval.  Then move to the next lowest date that doesn't belong to an interval and repeat till the list is empty.

Comment: yepp, i've figured it out, but i don't know how to move to the next lowest date, but I'm on it. :)

Comment: @Norbert you need `dates comparator` (google it), and storing dates on `List<Date>` that will be sorted with this comparator

Comment: yepp, actually I store these dates in a List<Date>.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to timestampes, and divide them (without remainder) by the intervall. All the dates with the same result belog to the same block.

```
/* Psydo Code */

int offset = firstTime.getTimeStamp() / intervallInMilliSec;
int max = lastTime.getTimeStamp() / intervallInMilliSec;
SortedSet<Date>[] result = new SortedSet<Date>[max - offset];
    for(int i = 0; i < max - offset] result[i] = new SortedSet<Date>();
for(Date time : fromFile) {
  result[(time.getTimeStamp() / intervallInMilliSec) - offset].add(time);
}
```

Comment: If you go this approach, be sure to use a `Collection` class that has a guaranteed iteration order so that when you pull the `Date` objects out of the `Collection` they'll be in some known order (preferably in the order they were added) so you can display them in the correct order.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic: did you mean the Set<Date>? -- It should be a List or a Sorted Set- correct.

Comment: Just a note: date objects have a natural chronological order when it comes to the default comparator :)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using the Joda Time library for this sort of thing:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

The built-in Java classes are rather difficult to work with - you will be constantly converting things to long, doing math, and then having to convert back to various Date & Calendar objects.  Joda takes care of all of that.